# Custom controls in 2008

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls

Using custom controls in VS 2008 shows frequent errors like 
object reference not set to an instance of an object  and 'could not be set on prperty'.

I have to use the existing custom control created by other team. But when implemeting those controls in my page show the error as i have mentioned

for an example

Section panel has the property collapsed = true or false but when i use this it shows me an error CustomControls:SectionPanel could not be set on property collapsed. Like this, for all the controls am getting error but not every time.

Comment: can you provide more information?

Comment: I am curious what about this question earned the upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/961847/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to talk to the team that developed the controls. Perhaps they didn't do a very good job developing them, or there is a specific way in which you need to install the controls.